# How to remove one document at the project aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb atlas, I have buid one value. these is the users collection sample document details.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f7de1f7e0044c8262f6adbc"},"bio":"Hi, I am a professional software developer, I have strong knowledge on coding.","email":"ats4@gmail.com","displayName":"ats demo","following":[],"name":"ats4demo6880904256665157633","image":" ","status":"active","isPrivate":false}
```

I tried to display all document except one.

```
"{\"collection\":\"users\",\"stages\":[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"%%args.user\"}},{\"following\":{\"$size\":0}}]}},{\"$lookup\":{\"from\":\"users\",\"localField\":\"status\",\"foreignField\":\"status\",\"as\":\"test\"}},{\"$unwind\":\"$test\"},{\"$project\":{\"test._id\":1,\"test.name\":1,\"test.displayName\":1,\"test.image\":1}}]}"
```

I have displayed all valuee except test._id: ObjectId("5f7f193585d5f70c177f6d27") at the project aggregate. but I can't.

can you please help me out with the solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a sample document from collection in json format. In image its not clear.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @wak786  I have updated the sample document, can you please help me with the solution \.

Comment: Based on the document you provided, can you help me understand, what are you looking for. Because i read the question but i think it is in the context of image you provided earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to understand the question. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f7de1f7e0044c8262f6adbc"
          }
        },
        {
          "following": {
            "$size": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "status",
      "foreignField": "status",
      "as": "test"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$test"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "test._id": {
        $not: {
          $eq: ObjectId("5f7de1f7e0044c8262f6adcc")
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "test._id": 1,
      "test.name": 1,
      "test.displayName": 1,
      "test.image": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Play around with the query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/38CPCP7X5qU)